# How to call method from jar file in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I have Java program in that I have database connectivity, and few methods to be call to run SQL query. I generated jar file for that java file using Apache ANT.
now I imported that jar file in my JSP. now how to call method `executeQuery(String sql)` from that jar file which is present in that Java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use external `.jars` in your webapp, these `JARs` must be placed under `WEB-INF/lib` folder and you want to call a method - `executeQuery(String sql)` defined in `XXXXX` class.

If that type `XXXX` is `public` and

1. Method executeQuery(String sql) is public static then call this method via
        `XXXX.executeQuery(param)` syntax;
2. If it is an `public` instance method then create an object of `XXXX` type and call it.

Answer (score 1):

Why import a separate jar file to perform this you should use

[**SQL TAG LIBRARY**](http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/insert-data-SqlJstlTag.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that in a JSP (presentation layer), but if you really want that you have to import the class/classes with the following line in JSP:

```
<%@ page import="package1.myClass1,package2.myClass2,....,packageN.myClassN" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly place your external .jar to the lib folder of your application (**WEB-INF/lib**) then simply you have to import that class or package of the jar file which you want to use by using import tag of the jsp.

```
<%@ page import="yourPackage.ClassName" %>
```

and now you can simply call your method on the object of that class as you do in simple java program