# Jar files in JSP not loading properly

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jar

This might be a duplicate, but I cannot find an answer using the below answers and many other sites on the internet...

My conundrum:

I am attempting to (poorly) run some classes from a jar in jsp.  Effectively what I have is the following:

```
<%@page import="edu.cs242.hadoop.*" %>
<%
... do some stuff ...
MRSearcher ss = new MRSearcher();
... do some stuff ...
%>
```

But every time I try to run the jsp I get the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /hadoop.jsp
MRSearcher cannot be resolved to a type
```

My webapp structure looks like:

```
/
|hadoop.jsp
|lucene.jsp
|index.jsp
|WEB-INF/
    |lib/
      |lucene.jar
      |hadoop.jar
    |classes/
      |*.java for our hadoop.jar
```

I've tried calling the jar itself and compiling the java through tomcat, both produce the same results.

Here is a snippet from our MRSearcher class:

```
package edu.cs242.hadoop;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;


/**
 * Created by cloudera on 3/10/14.
 */
public class MRSearcher {

    MRSearcher() {}

    public String[] run(String arg1, String arg2) {
        String[] things = new String[] {};
        // do stuff
        return things;
    }
}
```

There are other classes, but this one is the one that allows us to interface with the rest of the program.  The main is in a file called: Main.java, and it does nothing but runs this for command line output.  The syntax is correct as we can run the main and retrieve output.

I don't mean to sound insolent, but please don't comment on the futility and awfulness of including things like JAR files in JSP.  This is never going to production, it's a school project that doesn't need the necessity of correctness, it needs the necessity of functioning.  If I were doing this for a job I would do it right, but right now I don't care about learning about the correct way to separate logic and presentation layers in JSP -- I can do that just fine in other languages and understand the concept very well.

I have looked through and attempted to use the following solutions before posting this, all of this has failed:

- [how to run jar file methods in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638751/how-to-run-jar-file-methods-in-jsp)
- [How to call method from jar file in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024875/how-to-call-method-from-jar-file-in-jsp)
- [how to reference an external jar in jsp app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719824/how-to-reference-an-external-jar-in-jsp-app)

And more to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you kept `MRSearcher.class` file inside classes folder?

Comment: Yup.  It compiles just fine, no errors.

Comment: so whats the problem now?

Comment: See the error above.  It compiles but doesn't actually instantiate the constructor called.

Answer (score 0):

In `WEB-INF/classes/` you must have `MRSearcher.class` file. Keep in mind JSP files are compiled first time you access it, so your project can compile although your JSP are not well.

On the other hand, your `MRSearcher()` constructor must be `public`, if you omitte this, by default the constructor will be `package` and cannot be accessed from other packages. Check if your `Main.java` class is in same package of `MRSearcher`. If yes, this is why it can invoke `MRSearcher` constructor.

I hope this helps you.

Regards,

Comment: It is there and also the MRSearcher is in the compiled jar that resides in the /WEB-INF/lib file.  Everything is public.